# Maven EAR plugin - two libraries with a same ArtifactId

Tags: maven, ear

When an EAR module has two (or more) dependencies with a same artifactId, Maven copy those into the `/lib` directory and one rewrites the other. In the end there is only one library in the EAR.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>same-artifact</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group2</groupId>
    <artifactId>same-artifact</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there a possibility to manually rename a dependency (an alias?) or to copy the JARs with the whole name (`com.group1.same-artifact.jar` instead of only `same-artifact.jar`)?

EDIT:
It's all only about transitive dependencies, the final EAR **should** look like this:

```
/lib
    /com.group1.same-artifact.jar
    /com.group2.same-artifact.jar
/myModule.ejb
```

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: There is nothing special about my my poms, it's a standard multi project with an EJB and EAR projects. The only one problem is the two same artifacts those EAR plugin unpacks and rewrites...

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this problem. One is to change the [fileNameMapping](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#fileNameMapping) via configuration like this:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <fileNameMapping>full</fileNameMapping>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   [...]
</project>
```

which will use  `groupId+artifactId+version` of the artifacts for all of them.

Or you can make this change only for those [artifacts where a clash exsits](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html) like this:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <modules>
             <ejbModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
               <bundleFileName>anotherName-1.2.3.jar</bundleFileName>
             </ejbModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly have both those solutions a little bug:
1. not only libraries in `/lib` have the full names, but the modules as well
2. it works only for a module, not a transitive library as I need

Comment: Of course there is the option to use the full naming and then to rename the modules manually. This seems to be a not very clear solution, even for a workaround...

Comment: The first one is to map all file names which is not a bug ...it does exactly as stated. The question is how you get transitve deps into lib folder? Are you using skinnyWar's ? And yes the modules can be configured each separately if you need...Maybe you can make a suggestion to improve this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEAR

Comment: it's not a bug of the plugin, but would be a bug of my script if I made it like this :-) Unfortunatelly I don't believe there is a standard or just a nice solution for this, EAR plugin just can't deal with such a situation...